# How pause and resume download of s3 work by using objective C

Tags: amazon-s3

I am downloading images from s3 in one view controller(say First view controller) after tapping one downloaded image I have go on second view controller and also pause all the image request for some time and after doing some I have to resume all the download request .Please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Hi Ajay I am taking reference from this site  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html. for pausing all request I am doing   [transferManager pauseAll]; and for resuming all pauses request I am doing   [transferManager resumeAll:^(AWSRequest *request) {
    //Resume paused requests.
}]; . This code resumed my all request but I am unable to get notified when my download completed.